# Pass BrowserMob Proxy to Sauce Labs - "The proxy server is refusing connections" Error

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, saucelabs, browsermob

I have been trying to pass BrowserMob proxy to Sauce Labs with no luck.

Here's what I have tried:

- Start proxy server

  ```
  sh browsermob-proxy -port 9090
  ```
- Start proxy

  ```
  curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/proxy
  {"port":9091}
  ```
- Start sauce connect, and pass proxy server information

  ```
  java -jar Sauce-Connect.jar myname xxxxxx -p localhost:9091
  ```
- Run Java Client

  ```
  ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9091);
  proxyServer.start();    

  Proxy proxy = proxyServer.seleniumProxy();
  DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabillities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  capabillities.setCapability("version", "5");
  capabillities.setCapability("platform", Platform.XP);
  this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
          new URL("http://myname:xxxxxx@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
          capabillities);
  ```

The [following post](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2013/09/sauce-labs-and-yes-the-browsermob-proxy/) provides a general guide line regarding how to make it work, but I keep getting **"The proxy server is refusing connections"** error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

- Start Sauce Connect, and pass proxy server information

  ```
  java -jar Sauce-Connect.jar myname xxxxxx -p localhost:9091
  ```

  Running the above command will pass all requests to localhost 9091 port, and you may use `netcat` to confirm.

  ```
  nc -l 9091
  ```
- Run Java Client

  ```
  ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9091);
  proxyServer.start();    

  Proxy proxy = proxyServer.seleniumProxy();
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  // DO NOT set proxy for RemoteWebDriver
  // capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  capabilities.setCapability("version", "5");
  capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.XP);
  this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
          new URL("http://myname:xxxxxx@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
          capabillities);
  ```

  The Java Client should starts a proxy at Port 9091.  Unlike [using `FirefoxDriver` directly](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium), proxy should not be set in capabilities.

Comment: So, it works if you are using 1 thread right?  Obviously, this wouldn't work very well with multiple threads.

Comment: @Mingyu I am trying something similar, have one question though! Is it compulsory that the local machine where sauce-conncet is running and the sauce labs VM to be connected to same Network? or does this proxy work even if both local sauce-connect machine and sauce labs VM are present in different geo locations and connected to different Networks

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but try a different port (like `9090`). SauceConnect only proxies some ports for localhost as per the [docs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect#localhost)

Comment: The port mentioned above is for Proxy Server, which I need to daisy chain `Sauce Connect`.  Here's their FAQ: https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect#proxy